# Go: Get signal origin

Tags: go, signals

I'm using Go to launch a couple of scripts and when they have some problems they use the "alert" signal, I know Go can capture those signals but I need to know the PID that originated the Signal. in C to the signal handler is passed a structure to know the pid who originated the signal but in Go looks like is not the case

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)

func main() {

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)

    s := <-c
    fmt.Println("Got signal:", s)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",s)
}
```

the example below (extracted from the signal doc) send me the signal who originated the call but not any useful info (like the pid)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't do this in an officially supported manner. The Go runtime needs to own the signal handlers, and that extra information isn't exposed in any way.

You may still be able to do this from C by setting up a new signal handler, but I would be very cautious going about this (see issues like [issue/7227](http://golang.org/issue/7227)). You're probably better off using another method for communication other than a signal.

Here's a partial example based on Ian's code from issue 7227:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sigaction old_action;
void handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
    printf("Sent by %d\n", info->si_pid);
}

void test() {
    struct sigaction action;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, NULL, &action);
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof action);
    sigfillset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_sigaction = handler;
    action.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDSTOP | SA_SIGINFO | SA_ONSTACK;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, &old_action);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    C.test()
    pid := os.Getpid()
    for {
        syscall.Kill(pid, syscall.SIGUSR1)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: how "explosive" this aproach is? I mean, i only need the pid to get captured by a goroutine so i can kill the sender child, nothing fancy.

Comment: @Freaktor: It locks you into requiring cgo and linux, it may break at some point, and it's likely for something where there's probably a better way. Maybe if you better describe what "the alert" signal is, and why the go program has to be the one to kill the child.

Comment: im calling some nagios plugins and im currently using a timeout over the execution, but the nagios standard says that the plugins will emit the alert signal if they got some problem so im trying to capture that event.

Comment: @Freaktor: I still don't understand what you mean. There's no such thing as "the alert signal" that you could catch, and from what I understand of nagios plugins, they communicate via stdout and their return code. Can you reference the documentation so we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: im sorry the signal that looking is called alarm but looks like the documentation says is a per script self anti hang mesure, and the caller do not need to capture any signal (the stdout,exit codes and stderr part are covered) so lets call this as solved. thanks

Comment: So if I receive the "child exited" signal, Go doesn't want me to know which child it was?