# Find who sent a given signal

Tags: go, signals

I handle signals with a goroutine

```
func main() {
    csignals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(csignals)

    go func() {
        for {
            sig := <-csignals
            logger.Println("logger signal reçu: ", sig)
        }
    }()

    ...
}
```

However, I would like to find which process sent this signal. How could I do that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible right now to do this in Go. If you take a look at the implementation of the os.Signal interface you'll see it's basically an integer ( http://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go?s=2948:2963#L111 ). Why do you need to figure this out if I may ask? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: When you say process, do you mean a different program that runs in your system or is it a go routine?

Comment: @bshuster13 I don't mean goroutine nor program, I really mean process, as in BSD process. Not necessarily a different one either, as a process can send itself a signal (`man raise`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Golang: Get signal origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219751/golang-get-signal-origin)